Is there an way to convert "+02:00" to a TimeSpan?
I'm trying to convert time zone strings like "+02:00" and "-01:00" to a TimeSpan. I can't find a way to have the - or + sign in a format string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings
[TestMethod()]
public void ShouldParseTimeZoneStringToTimeSpan() 
{
    var value = "+02:00";
    var actual = 
        //TimeSpan.Parse(value);
        //DateTime.Parse(value).TimeOfDay;
        TimeSpan.ParseExact(value, "hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    var expected = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

Is there an elegant way to convert "+02:00" or "-02:00" to a TimeSpan?

Remove the - or + before trying to parse it...

If I had a method named "ShouldParseTimeZoneStringToTimespan()", I'd have it accept the string as input and return a TimeSpan as output (instead of void). I might also have a TryParseTimeZoneStringAsTimespan() that returns a bool and uses and out argument, similar to numeric and date TryParse() methods elsewhere in the framework.

@JoelCoehoorn It's a test method and only ment for clarification.

You can provide several formats for the ParseExact call. For example g to handle the -02:00 case and using escapes for the +02:00 - @"\+hh\:mm":
var values = new []
{
  ("-02:00", TimeSpan.FromHours(-2)), 
  ("+02:00", TimeSpan.FromHours(2))
};

foreach (var (value, expected) in values)
{
    var actual = TimeSpan.ParseExact(value, 
        new [] { @"\+hh\:mm", "g" },
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    
    Debug.Assert(actual == expected);
}

See also:

Custom TimeSpan format strings


TimeSpan represents time interval, so if you completely remove the - or + sign, it lost the whole point of using TimeSpan.
One of the default format type "g" actually allows "-" sign to represent negative time interval, but it's not allow "+", so you only have to remove the "+" from the string.
    [Fact]
    public void PositiveInterval()
    {
        string intervalString = "+02:00";
        var format = "g";
        var culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        TimeSpan.TryParseExact(intervalString.Replace("+", ""), format,
                                                          culture, TimeSpanStyles.None, out var result);

        Assert.NotEqual(TimeSpan.Zero, result);
        var expected = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
        Assert.Equal(expected, result);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void NegativeInterval()
    {
        string intervalString = "-02:00";
        var format = "g";
        var culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        TimeSpan.TryParseExact(intervalString.Replace("+", ""), format,
                                                          culture, TimeSpanStyles.None, out var result);

        Assert.NotEqual(TimeSpan.Zero, result);
        var expected = TimeSpan.FromHours(-2);
        Assert.Equal(expected, result);
    }


When using TryParse... you should evaluate the boolean result, because the out value is only valid if it returns true.

When it returns false, the out value is TimeSpan.Zero which is asserted.
